# Way to format Form with dynamic text fields c#

Tags: c#, textbox, tags, format, field

Right, so I have 13 textboxes with corresponding labels that are assigned after a user decides the name from a different form (instantiated by the 'Add field...' button). The issue arises when the user wishes to delete a textbox with previously entered data, as this results in an empty space where the textbox and label originally were as visualized by the following image:

[image]

My question is: how do I make it so that when a user chooses to delete a textbox, the textbox-label pair(s) that follow it replace the deleted textbox AND shift the remaining textboxes accordingly.

Textbox-label pairs in designer:
[image]

I've thought about this problem intensively over the past few days, and have concluded that with my current knowledge of C# I am limited to solving this issue with a horrendously tedious amount of if-statements (talking hundreds - thousands here). Any and all help would be appreciated!

Current code on the X-button for first textbox-label pair:

```
private void xButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label14.Text = "";
        textBox1.Text = "";
        if (label14.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            label14.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            xButton.Visible = false;
            label14.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
        if (!textBox2.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            label14.Text = label15.Text;
            textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text;
        }
        if (!textBox2.Text.Equals("") && (textBox3.Text.Equals("")))
        {
            label15.Visible = false;
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox2.Visible = false;
            xButton2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your code, *for ex*, for 3 labels/textboxes and how you would do it, so that we can improve it. In this form, you only want us to write it for you.

Comment: I'm not asking for it to be written, I'm asking how I could do this conceptually. Though I will post my current, ineffective, code as per request.

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for user controls (the name will vary depending on exactly what UI framework you are using).  Combine the label and edit into a single control, create and delete that single control as needed.

Comment: The way you seem to have implemented those additional fields seems to be static (hard-coded). If this is the case indeed that will cause lots of challenges including those you mentioned. What about using a dynamic approach which creates those controls on the fly (or optimized a custom control) and allows them to be deleted as well? The position will be automatically resolved if you chose the correct surrounding container.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst, that would work well with the creation of the new labels and textboxes, however how would I remove the newly created pair with the x-button? And would the following pairs automatically shift up when it is deleted? Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: If I was to design this I would probably create a custom control that consists of label, text box and X button. That control would provide an event which is raised when the X button is clicked, e. g. CloseClicked. The sourrounding control would listen to this event hence it gets a reference to it so it's easy to remove it from the child controls list of the surrounding container. The "shift" would automatically happen if the surrounding control supports it, e.g. a stack panel control.

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you could do is give all your "dynamic" controls (label, textbox, button) a similar value in their `Tag` property (in my example, I used the string `"dynamic"` for all the control `Tags`. This enables you to query for them easily.

Next, you could follow the logic that, anytime you delete some controls, you move all controls below the deleted ones up a distance equal to the height of the control being deleted plus whatever padding you have between the controls.

For example, when a user clicks the `X` button, since you know the value of the Bottom of the control that's being deleted, you could find all controls that had a matching `Tag` property whose Top is greater than the `x` button Bottom, and you can move them up.

Here's an example (this assumes that all your `X` buttons are mapped to this same click event):

```
private void buttonX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is represents the distance between the bottom 
    // of one control to the top of the next control
    // Normally it would be defined globally, and used when you
    // lay out your controls.
    const int controlPadding = 6;

    var xButton = sender as Button;
    if (xButton == null) return;

    var minTopValue = xButton.Bottom;
    var distanceToMoveUp = xButton.Height + controlPadding;

    // Find all controls that have the Tag and are at the same height as the button
    var controlsToDelete = Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(control =>
        control.Tag != null &&
        control.Tag.ToString() == "dynamic" &&
        control.Top == xButton.Top)
        .ToList();

    // Delete the controls
    controlsToDelete.ForEach(Controls.Remove);

    // Get all controls with the same tag that are below the deleted controls
    var controlsToMove = Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(control =>
        control.Tag != null &&
        control.Tag.ToString() == "dynamic" &&
        control.Top > minTopValue);

    // Move each control up the specified amount
    foreach (var controlToMove in controlsToMove)
    {
        controlToMove.Top -= distanceToMoveUp;
    }
}
```